# Java Reflection - Matching formal parameter list to actual parameter list

Tags: java, reflection

Let say I have a class `Foo` like this

```
public class Foo {
    public void setParameter(String name, Object value) {
       // ...
    }
}
```

I would like to get the `setParameter` method through reflection.

The problem is that in my code, I only know the **ACTUAL** parameters when I need to get this method. I have build a little method that can give me the `Class` array of actual parameters. Unfortunately the returned `Class` array from **actual parameters** `([String.class, String.class])` **doesn't match** the `Class` array of **formal parameters** `([String.class, Object.class])`  and `getDeclaredMethod` raises exception `NoSuchMethodException`.

Do you know of any library or code snippet that can help match the method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll probably need to be a little smarter about finding which method to call. One option is to iterate through each method from [`getDeclaredMethods()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods%28%29), first checking the name of the method to see if that's the one you want to call, then checking if the number of actual parameters matches the number of formal parameters, and lastly, if both of those are true, iterating through its actual parameters and checking if the parameter class is assignable from your formal parameter class.

One problem, however, is what happens if you have the methods:

```
public void setParameter(String name, Object value);
public void setParameter(String name, String value);
```

as both will match that test.

I don't know of any library of the top of my head that can handle that in a lightweight way. Though most dependency-injection frameworks (Spring, Guice) would have some support for it for their needs, and it may be worth looking into how they do things.

Jon Skeet's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/942208/84378) has an example of what I'm explaining.

Comment: In my case, the methods come from an interface and it provides only the first one.

Comment: @Stephan both methods are definitely acceptable in a class. The compiler will use the method that is a best match. If two methods are equally matched. (Object, String) and (String, Object), you'll be required to cast a parameter to direct the compiler to a specific method.

Comment: +1: You may need to iterate through the super classes methods as well, or use `getMethods();` to get the public methods.

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply use `getDeclaredMethods()` to get all maethods and then do the matching in your code, based on method name, parameter count and finally `Class.isAssignableFrom()` to check whether the parameters' types match the signature. That leaves cases where overloaded methods' signatures differ in types that can be compatible with the same concrete type (interfaces or super/subclasses). You have to decide whether your code has to support such corner cases.